# How to get javascript SignalR client to open when server not running initally

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr.client

So I've got a working client and server, GREAT!  Problem I'm running into is the following.

When the server is offline, I want the javascript/web client to open and display its interface and simply check every so often if the server is up yet, and once its up, connect.

Problem is the client throws an error that the hub is undefined and so the webpage won't open.  How can I get around this to achieve the results I'm looking for.

I've searched high and low and can't seem to find an example of this.
Any help/leads are appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using auto generating proxy download it and include with your client code?

Comment: Hmmm, never thought of that!  Is that something you can actually do in a proper way?  Or is it more of a hack?

Comment: Not using an autogenerated proxy is a perfectly valid approach. In fact there is even a tool that just does this. See this http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy for more details.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll let you know how this goes.